# Coefficients for Polynomials Giving Number of Paths of an LR Grid

Tags: combinatorics, functions, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

First, I want to say that I assume this problem has been looked at as it seems like a natural question to ask after being introduced to the boardwalk metric; however, I wouldn't know what to look up for information on this, and this is a personal project (meaning I don't want to just look up answers anyway).

Context:
I was attempting to count the number of efficient (no left or down movement) paths from the bottom vertex of an n*m grid to the top-right vertex. I made some rules that would give this:

1. (n,m)=(m,n)
2. (n,0)=1
3. (n,m)=(n,m-1)+(n-1,m)

However, this grows to a ridiculous amount of calculations, so I was able to make a calculator for this. By doing so, I found that (at least up to n=6) that there exists a polynomial of the nth degree which will calculate these out much quicker. The poly's I have thus far are: 
$$f_1(x)=x+1$$
$$f_2(x)=\cfrac{1}{2}x^2+\cfrac{3}{2}x+1$$
$$f_3(x)=\cfrac{1}{6}x^3+x^2+\cfrac{11}{6}x+1$$
$$f_4(x)=\cfrac{1}{24}x^4+\cfrac{5}{12}x^3+\cfrac{35}{24}x^2+\cfrac{24}{12}x+1$$
$$f_5(x)=\cfrac{1}{120}x^5+\cfrac{1}{8}x^4+\cfrac{17}{24}x^3+\cfrac{15}{8}x^2+\cfrac{137}{60)}+1$$
$$f_6(x)=\cfrac{1}{720}x^6+\cfrac{7}{240}x^5+\cfrac{35}{144}x^4+\cfrac{49}{48}x^3+\cfrac{203}{90}x^2+\cfrac{49}{20}x+1$$

Observations:
I see that the first coefficient will probably be $\cfrac{1}{n!}$ and the constant will be 1. Because of this, I assume it is possible for any n there exists a polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{c(n,i)}{n!}x^i$ that produces the number of paths in a grid. I've attempted to give every coefficient a form $\cfrac{c}{n!}$ to see if I could find any patterns in that, but to no avail thus far.

Tl;dr: I'm wanting to know if there exist methods where I could find this c(n,i) for any integer value n (producing as few of the functions as possible). I'm currently enrolled in a Real Analysis II course, so I would really like methods or texts to be within my paygrade; however, I would definitely be open to reading materials that are normally taught shortly after this course.

I would also like to apologize for the lack of tags; however, I'm not sure what area of math this topic, or the methods I could use to solve this problem, would be. Also, I would want to discuss a lot more about my "attempt at solutions," but I've been working on this problem for a week and the post would get cluttered quite quickly.

Comment: It appears that $c(n,i)={n+1\brack i +1}$, referring to the [unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind). It’s not obvious to me how  these polynomials produce the number of grid paths, can you say more about that?

Comment: They aren't proven, I tested up to 20x20 and found a polynomial from the first n number of the terms (n is the degree of the polynomial), this extended to the all the bigger grids, up to 20x20. However, checking bigger grids is extremely taxing on my pc, and I can't do much with it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The count is known to be $\binom{n+m}{n}=\binom{n+m}{m}$.  You can check that this formula satisfies your recurrence relations, or you can derive it combinatorially by noting that each such path takes $n+m$ steps and is completely determined by which steps are horizontal.

Comment: Oh... that's much simpler than I was expecting. Putting that into Google comes up with quite a few results on the topic, so I'll probably look into those as well. Thank you for your help.